# Jupyter Notebook vs Sublime Autocompletion not showing

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Jupyter's autocompletion (hitting tab) is incredibly useful. How do I get this to perform in a similar manner in Sublime? I hit ctrl+space but it gives me a list of pretty useless functions.

Is there a way to get Sublime to show the same thing that Jupyter Notebook shows?

Here's Jupyter Notebook (this is what I want to see in Sublime).

[image: Tab completion options in Jupyter Notebook]

Here's Sublime. Trying to get this to look like the above. The dropdown options in Sublime are useless here!

[image: Tab completion in Sublime]

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Sublime --> Tools --> Command Pallets --> Install Packages ---> Install Anaconda.

This should give you a nice plug in that makes a drop bar menu appear on Sublime.